# How to loop through unknown keys of a dict in qml code?

Tags: qt, qml, pyside

I have a small problem with qml code on how to display a dicitonary. On the python side I just have to declare it as QVariantMap

```
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, Signal
  
saved = Signal("QVariantMap")
```

I have managed to connect the signal well, and if i know the keys of the dictionary in advance i can display it well if I initialize it as property variant and then for example write saved["a"]

```
property variant saved: {"a": 0.0, "b": 0.0, "c": 0.0, "d": 0.0};
```

however my signal might come with less keys than the total. let's say it comes with keys "a" and "b". and I don't know in advance which keys (of the 4 total) will be in the signal. is there a way in qml to loop through its keys and then display their values??

The qt version I use is QtQuick 2.12

Thank you if you have a tip!

Comment: It should be a normal Javascript object by that point so this answer should work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object